TensorFlow: actual size of training data in custom Model.train_step
I want to create an Adversarial Autoencoder using Tensorflow. Right now, the Autoencoder part of my code works as it should. Now I want to add a layer, which encourages my model to map the latent code to a prior distribution. For this layer I want to generate as many samples from a prior distribution as there are samples passed to train_step. A discriminator should then be trained on random latent codes and on latent codes from the encoder of my model. But how do I determine the shape of the data passed into train_step?
This is my code so far:
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.

class Autoencoder(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, n_latent):
        super(Autoencoder, self).__init__()
        self.n_latent = n_latent
        self.encoder = keras.Sequential([
            keras.Input((28, 28)),
            layers.Flatten(),
            layers.Dense(n_latent),
        ])
        self.decoder = keras.Sequential([
            keras.Input(n_latent),
            layers.Dense(784, activation="sigmoid"),
            layers.Reshape((28, 28)),
        ])

        self.autoencoder = keras.Sequential([keras.Input((28, 28)), self.encoder, self.decoder])

    def call(self, inputs, training=False):
        return self.autoencoder(inputs, training=training)

    def train_step(self, data):
        if isinstance(data, tuple):
            data = data[0]

        # Right here, I want to generate random samples from a certain distribution
        # which is going to be a function based on numpy. It takes the shape of
        # the input data and generates "random" latent codes.

        # Unfortunately, I cannot access the data shape, as it's a Tensor with
        # only partially-known shape. Therefore, I cannot retrieve the tensor
        # shape using tf.shape(data), as the return value can't be used in numpy
        #batch_size = tf.shape(data)[0]
        #latent_real = np.random.normal(size=(batch_size, self.n_latent))

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            decoded = self.autoencoder(data, training=True)
            loss = self.compiled_loss(data, decoded)

        training_vars = self.autoencoder.trainable_variables
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, training_vars)

        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, training_vars))
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(data, decoded)

        return { m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}

ae = Autoencoder(32)
ae.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
ae.fit(x_train, epochs=10, batch_size=128)

As mentioned in the comment, I'm having troubles evaluating the actual shape of the input data. After some research, I heard terms like eager evaluation and graph mode but I cannot really make sense of those terms. Also, I found this (https://pgaleone.eu/tensorflow/2018/07/28/understanding-tensorflow-tensors-shape-static-dynamic/) resource regarding static and dynamic Tensor shapes, but it wasn't really helpful to me.
Is there another way I can make this work? I would actually like to stay flexible here and not switch to a Tensorflow based function with works with lazily evaluated Tensors. The functions which return values drawn from a prior distribution already exist and I don't want to change them.
EDIT: If I don't specify a batch size in ae.fit(x_train, epochs=10) or set it to the default of 32, I can access the input tensor shape and will get an actual value instead of a dynamically evaluated Tensor. What is happening here?
